Remove show applications and sidebar completely in ubuntu 20.04
I had developed a GUI using pyside6 and it launches fullscreen when power on but in touch screen dragging the  software from left moves it to the show applications side bar ,is there any way to remove the show applications sidebar permanantly.enter image description here


You can disable the Gnome Shell extension "Ubuntu Dock". That would fully and permanently remove the applications sidebar.
To enable: Turn off the "Ubuntu Dock" system extension using the "Extensions" tool.

You can have the dock hidden only when an application is covering it.
To enable: Settings - Appearance - check "Autohide the dock". This assumes that "intellihide"  is set to "true", the default.
Using the command line:
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide true


You can have the dock hidden by default, so it is revealed only when moving with the mouse to the left edge.
To enable you need to resort to the command line or dconf-editor, because the "intellihide"  setting is not exposed.
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false



